# Created a Registration Activity, Everything works fine except the last two inputs which are Password & Confirm password

Tags: java, android, if-statement, android-toast

[image: Register Activity]

The toast messages or errors of both password & confirm password doesn't show at all. Username, email is working fine. What could be the problem ?. First i tried to make different methods for username validation, email validation, password validation & confirm password but was having interrupted toasts then I just removed the methods and compiled them in one method but still having this last issue.

```
package com.example.foodeezfavourite;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText;
public class RegistrationActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextInputEditText registrationUserName;
    EditText registrationEmail, registrationPassword, registrationConfirmPassword;
    Button registrationButton;
    String userName, email, password, confirmPassword, emailPattern, passwordPattern;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_registration);

        registrationUserName = findViewById(R.id.edRegisterUserName);
        registrationEmail = findViewById(R.id.edRegisterEmail);
        registrationPassword = findViewById(R.id.edRegisterPassword);
        registrationConfirmPassword = findViewById(R.id.edRegisterConfirmPassword);
        registrationButton = findViewById(R.id.btnRegisterButton);

        registrationButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                userName = registrationUserName.getText().toString();
                email = registrationEmail.getText().toString();
                password = registrationPassword.getText().toString();
                confirmPassword = registrationConfirmPassword.getText().toString();
                emailPattern = "[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-z]+\\.+[a-z]+";
                passwordPattern = "^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[@#$%^&+=!])(?=\\S+$).{4,}$";

                validationProcess();
            }
        });

    }

    public void validationProcess() {
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(userName) && TextUtils.isEmpty(email) && TextUtils.isEmpty(password) && TextUtils.isEmpty(confirmPassword)) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please fill all details", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else if (TextUtils.isEmpty(userName)) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Username field is Empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else if (userName.length() < 3) {
            registrationUserName.setError("Username must be at least 3 letters long");
        } else if (userName.length() > 12) {
            registrationUserName.setError("Username must be less than 12 letters");
        } else if (TextUtils.isEmpty(email)) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Email field is Empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else if (!email.matches(emailPattern)) {
            registrationEmail.setError("Invalid Email Address");
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Email must contain at least 1 Uppercase letter, " + "1 lowercase letter, 1 number & 1 special character", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else if (email.matches(emailPattern)) {
            registrationEmail.setError(null);
        } else if (TextUtils.isEmpty(password)) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Password field is Empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else if (!password.matches(passwordPattern)) {
            registrationPassword.setError("Invalid Password");
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Password must contain at least 1 Uppercase letter, " + "1 lowercase letter, 1 number & 1 special character", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else if (password.matches(passwordPattern)) {
            registrationPassword.setError(null);
        } else if (password.compareTo(confirmPassword) == 0) {
            registrationPassword.setError(null);
        } else if (password.compareTo(confirmPassword) != 0) {
            registrationPassword.setError("Passwords does not match");
        } else if (TextUtils.isEmpty(confirmPassword)) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Confirm Password field is Empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I was new to boolean methods, so did'nt know much about them but found a video on youtube (HOW TO) and solved the problem. I wasn't returning any false value so all the toasts were being interrupted and also some conditions were not working.

changed the void method to boolean.

```
package com.example.foodeezfavourite;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class RegistrationActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText registrationEmail, registrationPassword, registrationConfirmPassword, registrationUserName;
    Button registrationButton;
    String userName, email, password, confirmPassword, emailPattern, passwordPattern;
    boolean dataRecorded;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_registration);

        registrationUserName = findViewById(R.id.edRegisterUserName);
        registrationEmail = findViewById(R.id.edRegisterEmail);
        registrationPassword = findViewById(R.id.edRegisterPassword);
        registrationConfirmPassword = findViewById(R.id.edRegisterConfirmPassword);
        registrationButton = findViewById(R.id.btnRegisterButton);

        registrationButton.setOnClickListener(view -> {
            userName = registrationUserName.getText().toString();
            email = registrationEmail.getText().toString();
            password = registrationPassword.getText().toString();
            confirmPassword = registrationConfirmPassword.getText().toString();
            emailPattern = "[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-z]+\\.+[a-z]+";
            passwordPattern = "^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[@#$%^&+=!])(?=\\S+$).{8,}$";

            dataRecorded = isAllEmpty();

            if (dataRecorded == true) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Data Recorded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
            }
        });
    }

    public Boolean isAllEmpty() {
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(userName) && TextUtils.isEmpty(email) && TextUtils.isEmpty(password) && TextUtils.isEmpty(confirmPassword)) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please fill all details", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return false;
        } else if (TextUtils.isEmpty(userName)) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Username field is Empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return false;
        } else if (userName.length() < 3) {
            registrationUserName.setError("Username must be at least 3 letters long");
            return false;
        } else if (userName.length() > 12) {
            registrationUserName.setError("Username must be less than 12 letters");
            return false;
        } else if (TextUtils.isEmpty(email)) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Email field is Empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return false;
        } else if (!email.matches(emailPattern)) {
            registrationEmail.setError("Invalid Email Address");
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Email must contain at least 1 Uppercase letter, " + "1 lowercase letter, 1 number & 1 special character", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return false;
        } else if (TextUtils.isEmpty(password)) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Password field is Empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return false;
        } else if (!password.matches(passwordPattern)) {
            registrationPassword.setError("Invalid Password");
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Password must contain at least 1 Uppercase letter, " + "1 lowercase letter, 1 number, 1 special character & must be 8 characters long ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return false;
        } else if (TextUtils.isEmpty(confirmPassword)) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Confirm Password field is Empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return false;
        } else if (password.compareTo(confirmPassword) != 0) {
            registrationPassword.setError("Passwords does not match");
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```